# multiselection listView contains checkBoxes

Tags: java, android

I have ListView with check boxes  the app delete the checked items ;; and should delet teh items that have the same id with the checked items :
here's my code

```
private class CAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private ArrayList<Entity> list;
        private Context context;
        String Status;
        CAdapter(Context context,
                ArrayList<Entity> getC) {
            this.context = context;
            this.list = getC;
             Status="";
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            TextView Name;
            TextView Desc;

            Button deleteBtn;

            CheckBox CBox;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return list.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }




        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final ViewHolder holder;
            final CEntity CObj = list.get(position);

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.custom_list_view_confirmed, parent,
                        false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();


                holder.Name = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.Name);



                holder.Desc = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.activity1);





                holder.deleteBtn = (Button) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.deleteBtn);

                holder.CBox=(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.isCheck);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }








            if (CObj.getMystatus().equals(
                    context.getResources().getString(R.string.course_status_delete))) {
                holder.status.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            } else if (attemptedCourseObj.getMystatus().equals(
                    context.getResources().getString(R.string.course_status_pending))) {
                holder.status.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            } else if (attemptedCourseObj.getMystatus().equals(
                    context.getResources().getString(R.string.course_status_update))) {
                holder.status.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            }

            holder.Name.setText(attemptedCourseObj.getCourseName());







            holder.CBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(holder.CBox.isChecked()){
                         if(list.contains(getItem(position))){
                             list.remove(getItem(position));
                             }
                    }
                }

            });
//          

            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

the problem is when delete the checked it dosent delete the item that have the same id .

```
int pos=Data.CList.size();
            SparseBooleanArray checked=CListView.getCheckedItemPositions();
             for (int n = pos; n > 0; n--){
                 if (checked.get(n)){
                 code=Data.inList.get(n).getCCode();
                 Data.inList.remove(n);

                 }else if(CList.get(n).equal(code){
Data.inList.remove(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to refresh the list with notifydatasetchanged and be sure that you delete the entire object from the list

Answer (score 0):

You need to inform your `adapter` with the new modifications by giving the `adapter` the new dataset after removing the deleted elements from it and notify with the changes. You can do this as the following:
1)Add method into your `adapter` to set the new data as following:

```
public void setNewData(ArrayList<Entity> newEntities){
    this.list = newEntities;
}
```

2)From the `activity` or the `fragment` call the previous method with the new data and call this line to notify the `adapter` with the changes

```
myAdapter.setNewData(myNewEntities);
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanges();
```

Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example/5092426#5092426) for more info about `NotifyDataSetChanges()` method